# Android App crashing in Emulator

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm a novice android app developer. I wrote an application which fetches Bible Readings from online. I wrote the separate Java class for fetching the reading and I tested it and it's working fine. But when I tried to use that in my Android App, my app crashed and stops working. I've understood from the logs that it's throwing a null pointer exception, but I don't how to fix that. I've also checked the internet and I can't find an exact solution for this. I'm attaching the logs and file related to my application below. Could anyone go through my code and throw some light on fixing the error. I appreciate your time on my behalf and many thanks in advance.

```
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mgocsm/com.mgocsm.EveningKymthaPrayers}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.mgocsm.BibleReader.getVerses(BibleReader.java:44)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.mgocsm.EveningKymthaPrayers.onCreate(EveningKymthaPrayers.java:25)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-25 09:49:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  ... 11 more

EveningKymthaPrayers.java (Activitiy from where I call the Java class to fetch readings)
=========================
```

.

```
public class EveningKymthaPrayers extends Activity {
    AssetManager am;
    FileReader f;
    TextView kymtha_prayer;
    BibleReader bible;
    //ReadingList rl = new ReadingList();
    @Override   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.evening_kymtha);        
        am = getAssets();
        f = new FileReader(am,"kymtha.txt");               
        kymtha_prayer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_kymtha);    
        kymtha_prayer.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        bible = new BibleReader("John 3:16-17");
        kymtha_prayer.setText(bible.getVerses());        
        //kymtha_prayer.setText(f.readFile());
        //kymtha_prayer.setText(setText);                          
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**BibleReader.java** (Java class for fetching Bible verses)

```
public class BibleReader {
    public static final String  URL="http://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=";
    String verse;   
    String logName = "BibleReader";
    String line;
    StringBuilder recText;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 10;    
    private final byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    public BibleReader(String verse) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.verse = verse; 
        this.verse = this.verse.toString().replaceAll(" ", "%20");      
    }

    public String getVerses() 
    {
        String body = null;
        try{        
            URL url = new URL(URL+this.verse);
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
            String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
            encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = in.read(dataBuffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(dataBuffer, 0, len);
            }   
            body = new String(baos.toByteArray(), encoding);
            Log.d(logName, "Fetched Verse"+body);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d(logName, e.getMessage());
        }               
        return body.toString();     
    }

}
```

**AndroidMainfest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mgocsm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DailyPrayers" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>        
        <activity android:name=".EveningPrayers" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".EveningKymthaPrayers" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity> 
    </application>  
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.daily_prayers:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DailyPrayers.class));
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

**DailyPrayers.java**

```
public class DailyPrayers extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.daily_prayers);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.home:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.evening_prayers:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EveningPrayers.class));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**EveningPrayers.java**

```
public class EveningPrayers extends Activity {

    @Override   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.evening_prayers);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.kymtha_evening:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EveningKymthaPrayers.class));          
            break;
        case R.id.sleeba_evening:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you debug a bit? The log tells you more than enough - it's `Log.d()` call that crashes inside `getVerses()`... Perhaps exception thrown has no message attached?

Comment: `println needs a message` that means you are trying to print the value which is null.so what you need to do is comment your all Logs and run again,see is it working or not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Println needs a message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443205/println-needs-a-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i have noticed in your code:

- `bible.getVerses()` is returning **null**
- It seems **INTERNET** permission is not included in AndroidManifest.xml file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`

- Don't make a web call on Main thread. Instead you can use `AsyncTask` or `AsyncTaskLoader`
- Instead of using:

`this.verse = this.verse.toString().replaceAll(" ", "%20");`

You must use:

```
String webURL = URLEncoder.encode("your web url", "utf-8");
```

Comment: A Big thanks for taking time to answer my question, I've made the changes and implemented Web Call using ASyncTask and it worked fine. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: @user1202047 As per SO rule, you need to accept one answer and upvote it if you found it helpful.

Comment: I've chosen your reply as the answer, but I can't able to Vote Up, it says I need 15 reputation :(

Answer (score 1):

The body that you are trying to print is getting null as a value.Check first you receive any value in body or not.

Comment: A Big thanks for taking time to answer my question, I've made the changes and implemented Web Call using ASyncTask and it worked fine. Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

What are you logging at this place: `com.mgocsm.BibleReader.getVerses(BibleReader.java:44)`
 ?
You are probably passing a Null.

Comment: A Big thanks for taking time to answer my question, I've made the changes and implemented Web Call using ASyncTask and it worked fine. Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

 body = new String(baos.toByteArray(), encoding);
            Log.d(logName, "Fetched Verse"+body);
```

your Body is getting null value that is why ur log is giving nullpointer exception

Comment: A Big thanks for taking time to answer my question, I've made the changes and implemented Web Call using ASyncTask and it worked fine. Much appreciated!!!